# Are there any thesauruses or publications that deal with the differentiation of near-synonyms in native/aboriginal/endangered languages?

Tags: semantics, lexicography, endangered-languages

I'm looking for any publications or thesauruses that deal with the differentiation of near-synonyms in any of the endangered/native languages (especially something that deals with a large chunk of the lexicon rather than just a few words of interest).

It's difficult to find a good thesaurus that explains the differences between synonyms even for some of the major languages. So I wonder: has any substantial work in this direction ever been done for any "minor" language (say, for a Native American one).

Among other things, I'm really interested in the methods they might've used, because I imagine making a thesaurus for an endangered language would be quite different from making one for English or Spanish (and likely involve working with informers extensively).

Comment: The difference between a thesaurus and a dictionary for an endangered language is not rigidly observed. Particularly when the language is polysynthetic, there is not much difference to observe. Take a look at Bates, Hess, and Hilbert's [_Lushootseed Dictionary_](https://www.amazon.com/Lushootseed-Dictionary-Thom-Hess/dp/0295973234), or ...

Comment: ... or Ken Hill's [Hopi dictionary/Hopìikwa lavàytutuveni:](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/language-in-society/article/abs/hill-kenneth-c-editor-in-chief-hopi-dictionaryhopiikwa-lavaytutuveni-a-hopienglish-dictionary-of-the-third-mesa-dialect-with-an-englishhopi-finder-list-and-a-sketch-of-hopi-grammar-compiled-by-the-hopi-dictionary-project-bureau-of-applied-research-in-anthropology-university-of-arizona-tucson-university-of-arizona-press-1998-pp-xviii-900-hb-8500/5043A35A71E882C3DD5D6669F9518E48)

Comment: @jlawler, thanks, but I don't mean just any wordbook that's organized by meaning rather than alphabetically. Say, I'm learning English and I want to learn the exact difference between "goal" and "purpose". For English, there are resources that explain it: there are thesauruses that not just list synonyms together, but explain the subtle differences between them. And there are research papers on a lot of synonyms. I wonder if something like that has ever been done on "minor" languages.

Comment: That distinction presupposes that there is a fairly precise criterion for what's a "word" and what's a "synonym". Most languages -- especially endangered ones -- often don't have either, and for some -- like Greenlandic Eskimo -- there really isn't a great difference between "word" and "sentence".

Comment: @jlawler, not necessarily, because one could be studying distinctions between near-synonymous morphemes, phrases or constructions just as much as between words. Thinking of synonyms as of words is just something that we assume for most "major" languages, because it seems to work well for those languages.

Comment: "Minor" languages, in terms of population, often have enough variation to afford to give everybody their own synonyms, especially in auxiliary languages (see [Hale on Walbiri](http://lingphil.mit.edu/papers/hale/papers/hale095.pdf)), or for neighborly mocking (see [Sapir on Nootka](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=inu.30000087080705&view=1up&seq=9)),